# How can I create circular animation like below video in swift5?

Tags: swift, animation, progress-bar, swift5

Here is the sample demo video for my expected output. need to do blink animation after filling certain value

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OPY36Tq63p3qcHLxrfuxGARDDk-QCIrt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "You need access". That link is private. You need to go to your Google drive and make it public.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OPY36Tq63p3qcHLxrfuxGARDDk-QCIrt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The second link doesn't work either. And don't post a comment, edit your original question so that people get to the right place without having to hunt through a bunch of comments.

Comment: Check your mail inbox

Comment: You should describe the effect you are after in words in your question.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "...I can't create the second circular progress animation on first one." You posted a single video. What is the "second circular progress animation"? What is the "first one"?

Comment: Hi @DuncanC, I just want the circular progress as same as video(with blink animation)! I have no idea how can I do it,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231528/discussion-between-leena-and-duncan-c).

Comment: I don't have access to the SO chat feature from work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for circular animation progress bar :

> https://github.com/MatiBot/MBCircularProgressBar

Comment: Thanks Bikesh, is any idea about add blink animation?

Comment: add blink animation on uiview or imageview ?